# How to make relationship between parent and child table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

I am learning postgresql, I am struggling while making relationship between parent table and child table. any help would be appreciated.

This is my parent table.

Table Name  **Country**

```
c_id   state    No_of_cities    Total Population
1     state1    30                60
2     state2    40                70
3     state3    50                80
```

Here is my child's table details-

Table Name  **state1**

```
s_id    cities  population
1       city1   234
2       city2   345
```

Table Name  **state2**

```
s_id    cities  population
1      city3    544
2      city4    765
```

Table Name  **state3**

```
s_id    cities  population
1      city1    543
2      city5    987
```

Please help me to figure out, how to make relationship between tables, So that I can get accurate data while query .

Comment: You can't do that because you shouldn't have a table for each row, you should have a table for Country, State and City. Search information about "database table normalization" so you can learn how properly design the tables and their relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have only one table for the cities of all states:

For example:

**Table Name states**

```
state    no_of_cities   population
state1   20             60
state2   30             70
state3   40             80
```

**Table Name cities**

```
state       cities   population
state1      city1    234
state1      city2    345
state2      city3    544
state2      city4    765
state3      city1    543
state3      city5    987
```

then you can add a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE cities ADD FOREIGN KEY (state) REFERENCES states (state);
```

but first you must set the states primary key

```
ALTER TABLE states ADD PRIMARY KEY (state)
```

or (if you want a integer id as pk) add a unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE states ADD UNIQUE (state)
```